# Twitter Share Callback From Custom Twitter Button

Tags: javascript, twitter

I am implemented a custom twitter button by using the following

```
   var url = attrs.twitterShare;
   var width = 575; 
   var height = 400; 
   var left = (getScreenWidth() - width) / 2; 
   var top = (getScreenHeight() - height) / 2; 
   var opts = 'status=1' + ',width=' + width + ',height=' + height + ',top=' + top + ',left=' + left;

   window.open('http://twitter.com/share?original_referer=' + url, 'twitter_share', opts);
```

Summary, an element is clicked which calls the javascript open that opens up twitter.com/share with the url to be shared. But I wondering is there a callback I can use to get stats on the share linked such as the number of retweets?

Answer (score 0):

You could embed an iframe in the popup window, which loads the share url, and when the page changes you can handle the

```
function callback(url) { alert(url); };
var window = open('url','name','height=300,width=300');
window.document.write('<iframe onLoad="window.opener.callback(this.contentWindow.location);" src="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url=http%3A%2F%2Fbbc.co.uk&text=This is a Twitter title">');
```